# What input format does m2stitch.stitch_images() require?

Tags: python, numpy, image-stitching

I'm trying to stitch some microscope images with the help of the m2stitch library.

The only example on how to use it is in the docs: https://m2stitch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

Unfortunatelly, I cannot figure out what format my input needs to be in. In the example, it loads a bunch of .npy images from a directory directly with np.load(). I cannot get this to work due to some other permission issues.

I can however transform the images i want to stitch to .npy files.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import m2stitch

image1 = np.load(r'A61_20230123113809.npy')
image2 = np.load(r'A62_20230123113809.npy')
image3 = np.load(r'A63_20230123113809.npy')
image4 = np.load(r'A64_20230123113809.npy')

images = np.array(image1, image2, image3, image4)

rows = [0,1]
cols = [0,1]

result_df, _ = m2stitch.stitch_images(images, rows, cols, row_col_transpose=False)
```

The line that I cannot get to work to give me the correct format is this:

```
images = np.array(image1, image2, image3, image4)
```

Any idea what format of "images" is needed for "stitch_images" to work?

Comment: Can't help you with that but If you want to give [stitching](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching) a try I might be able to help

Comment: @LukasWeber thanks, but unfortunatelly I was not succesful with the stitching library for my usecase because the images are microscope images with repeating patterns. m2stitch is more specific for this usecase...

Comment: Maybe you want to share a sample dataset? I would be interested in how m2stitch handles this